# datepicker min date change dynamically in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I have a min date taken dynamically. I get the value from my controller as 'setmax'.
I need to give this value to my datepicker mindate.

I ahev tried this by setting

```
$scope.minDate = $scope.setmax;
```

inside my controller. But it is not taking this value.

Is it possible to give like this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
                               ng-model="myModel.vdate"
                               placeholder="Amount valid date"
                               is-open="startOpened"
                               ng-init="startOpened = false"
                               min-date="{{secmax}}"
                               max-date="end"
                               required
                               close-text="Close"
                               ng-click="startOpen($event)"
                               name="datevalidity"/>
```

Comment: is the value `setmax` or `$scope.setmax`? pls post your controller code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
                           ng-model="myModel.vdate"
                           placeholder="Amount valid date"
                           is-open="startOpened"
                           ng-init="startOpened = false"
                           min-date="setmax"
                           max-date="end"
                           required
                           close-text="Close"
                           ng-click="startOpen($event)"
                           name="datevalidity"/>
```

Comment: YAH. SURE. THANKU SO MUCH. tHIS MISTAKE EATS MY HOURS..:)